# Default milliseconds to 0 in Oracle

Tags: oracle, timestamp, milliseconds

I have a timestamp column in Oracle that has format 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI.SxFF6'. 
The data looks like below:

```
11/09/1917 10:45:28.230000
10/19/2014 18:09:28.410000
12/19/2011 11:06:28.340000
```

I need the timestamp to retain the value except for getting the milliseconds which need to be defaulted to 000000.
I tried query -

```
cast(to_char(Local_time, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as timestamp(6))
```

But it is throwing error - `"Not valid month"`

Does anyone have any ideas on what I can try to get milliseconds to 0. I use Toad to query the table.

Comment: Why do you try to cast a `TIMESTAMP` into a `VARCHAR2`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `TIMESTAMP` value does not have any format. All you have is a default **display** format - defined by current user `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` setting.

Try this one:

```
CAST(Local_time AS TIMESTAMP(0))
```

If you like to trunc the milliseconds but haven them still available use

```
CAST(CAST(Local_time AS TIMESTAMP(0)) AS TIMESTAMP(6))
```

Comment: I tried. The column is timestamp data type and using your cast(col as timestamp(0) gets me the timestamp without milliseconds and with an Am/PM. I want it to be in 24 HR format

Comment: Again, it returns a `TIMESTAMP` which itself does not have any format! Change your `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` setting for default display or use `TO_CHAR` function.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
SQL> create table test (col timestamp, result timestamp);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (col) values (to_timestamp('11/09/1917 15:45:28.230000', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF6'));

1 row created.

SQL> update test set result = cast(col as date);

1 row updated.

SQL> select * From test;

COL                       RESULT
------------------------- -------------------------
09.11.17 15:45:28,230000  09.11.17 15:45:28,000000

SQL>
```